# Why F# code yields different result than C#

Tags: c#, f#, webrequest, translate

How come that this C# code works, but not the equivalent F# version (run through F# interactive)? Result should be an HTML table with figures only.

C# VERSION:

```
    var url = "https://www.investing.com/instruments/HistoricalDataAjax";

    var httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    httpRequest.Method = "POST";

    httpRequest.Headers["Origin"] = "http://www.investing.com";
    httpRequest.Headers["X-Requested-With"] = "XMLHttpRequest";
    httpRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    httpRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/51.0.2704.79 Chrome/51.0.2704.79 Safari/537.36";

    var data = "curr_id=1073048&smlID=2627117&header=SE0010296574%20Historical%20Data&st_date=04%2F12%2F2020&end_date=05%2F12%2F2021&interval_sec=Daily&sort_col=date&sort_ord=DESC&action=historical_data";

    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpRequest.GetRequestStream()))
    {
        streamWriter.Write(data);
    }

    var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }

    Console.WriteLine(httpResponse.StatusCode);
```

F# VERSION:

```
let url = "https://www.investing.com/instruments/HistoricalDataAjax"
let httpRequest = WebRequest.Create(url) :?> HttpWebRequest
httpRequest.Method <- "POST"
httpRequest.Headers.["Origin"] <- "http://www.investing.com"
httpRequest.UserAgent <- "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/51.0.2704.79 Chrome/51.0.2704.79 Safari/537.36"
httpRequest.Headers.["X-Requested-With"] <- "XMLHttpRequest"
httpRequest.ContentType <- "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
let data = "curr_id=1073048&smlID=2627117&header=SE0010296574%20Historical%20Data&st_date=04%2F12%2F2020&end_date=05%2F12%2F2021&interval_sec=Daily&sort_col=date&sort_ord=DESC&action=historical_data";
let streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpRequest.GetRequestStream())
streamWriter.Write(data)
let httpResponse = httpRequest.GetResponse() :?> HttpWebResponse
let streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream())
let html = streamReader.ReadToEnd()
printfn "%A" httpResponse.StatusCode
```

Comment: When you say that the F# version doesn't work, what does that mean? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 6):

*(Updated)*

You get different results because the POST is sent without the body. The stream writer needs to flushed:

```
( use streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpRequest.GetRequestStream())
  streamWriter.Write(data) )
```

Comment: The weird thing is that the F# code executes without errors, but the data retrieved from the server are different! With the F# version, the website main page is retrieved, whereas the C# code retrieves an HTML data table (which is correct). I've copied/pasted URLs and all request information, still different result, so strange. I'm now considering keeping the C# version and invoke it in F# as a DLL, clunky but works at least.

Comment: It's not a weird thing at all. In C# code you're closing `streamWriter` before sending the request, but in F# code you're not. The code is different. So different results are very much expected.

Comment: To be even more consistent with the C# code the following needs updating too: ```( use  streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()) let result = streamReader.ReadToEnd() printfn "%A" result ) printfn "%A" httpResponse.StatusCode ```,  it is important to note that otherwise the F# is not the same as the C#